How to pass a variable to a prompt and get it printed as is in Python
I'm working on a project where I need to pass a variable to a prompt and get it printed as part of the output string. I'm using Python and the OpenAI API. Specifically, I have a function that identifies non-inclusive pronouns in a given text. The identified pronouns are stored in a variable which I want to include in the prompt string for further processing.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import re

def identify_non_inclusive_pronouns(text):
    pronouns = ['he', 'she', 'his', 'him', 'her', 'she\'s']
    # Remove text inside parentheses
    text = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', text)
    words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
    non_inclusive_pronouns = [word for word in words if word in pronouns]
    unique_non_inclusive_pronouns = list(set(non_inclusive_pronouns))
    return unique_non_inclusive_pronouns


def classify_sentences(message: str):
    non_inclusive_pronouns = identify_non_inclusive_pronouns(message)
    print(non_inclusive_pronouns)
    non_inclusive_pronouns_str = ', '.join(non_inclusive_pronouns)
    print(non_inclusive_pronouns_str)
    system_content = '''
    __CONTEXT__:
    You are a World-Class Inclusive Language Checker, tasked with evaluating English messages for any type of bias. Your objective is to ensure the language used is inclusive, avoiding any words or phrases that could offend any community, ethnic group, race, gender, religious group, socio-economic status, or societal segment.You will be working for the corporate affairs team of Mars Wrigley, a pet care and confectionery giant, to ensure that the posts on various social media platforms are inclusive and respectful.The language should be neutral ,respectable and relatable to everyone inclusive of individuals of any gender,race, caste, creed, religious or socio-economic community. Accurate inclusivity detection is crucial as failure to detect correctly would negatively impact business users and content consumers and will cost the human race.
    __ASK__: 
    Classify the message as "Inclusive" or "Not Inclusive".
    Output for "Not Inclusive" messages:
    Not Inclusive Words: A list of non-inclusive words or phrases.
    Reasons: Detailed explanations for why each word or phrase flagged is considered non-inclusive with inclusive reccomendations.
    __CONSTRAINTS__:
    1. Ensure the model scans the entire text for all predefined inclusivity rules.
    2. Each rule should be independently checked so that multiple issues can be identified within the same passage.Even if one rule is violated the  final outcome is non inclusive and reasons and non inclusivity words should be listed appropriately.
    3. For each instance of non-inclusivity, add the specific non-inclusive words and the corresponding reasons on why the text was flagged and recommendations to the output lists.
    4.Always add a comment under reasons even if the text is inclusive.There are some good to have comments or reccomendation to the user suggested by most of the  rules.

    Given the MESSAGE, let's go step by step using rules to learn how to check if the message is inclusive or not:

    1. **Important Rule:** Retrieval of pronoun variable
        Expected Output:
        - Tag: Not Inclusive
        - not_inclusive_words: Append content of string {non_inclusive_pronouns_str} to this list
        - Reasons: Include the appropriate pronouns in brackets next to 'name/job title' the first time they are mentioned in the message/post.

        OUTPUT:
        {{
        "tag": "Not Inclusive",
        "not_inclusive_words": {non_inclusive_pronouns},
        "reasons": ["Include the appropriate pronouns in brackets next to 'name/job title' the first time they are mentioned in the message/post."]
        }}
    '''
    # Processing with the model here...

Even after I did as above I am not getting the LLM to print the retrieved list of pronouns and tag correctly. As it's rule based I am expecting it to work 100% of the times. And note I definitely want to pass the pronouns to the prompt because I want the LLM to  get it to reason. I am using GPT-4o.

system_content needs to be an f-string to substitute variables. So use f''' instead of just '''.

I tried it with f``` as well it is not printing it as intended

Use f-strings to insert your variable into your text. Since f-strings use curly braces to denote variables, but your text also has literal curly braces, you'll have to escape those with a double brace.
Example:
test_var = ['his', 'her', 'he', 'she']

print(f'''Big
Multiline
string
with braces
{{{{{test_var}}}}}
''')

Output:
Big
Multiline
string
with braces
{{['his', 'her', 'he', 'she']}}


I have added those curly braces for it to understand it is a variable. I really do not need curly braces for display.

Update the question and show what you actually want in the prompt. If you don't want the square brackets, use {", ".join(non_inclusive_pronouns)} @Quest
